# How to substitute Node.js dependency with `require()` with ES6 dynamic imports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, require, dynamic-import

I'm having a real hard time getting my head around the ES6 dynamic import Syntax with regards to replacing a module loaded with Node.js's `require`.

Here's the relevant part my original code:

```js
export default class Module extends React.Component {
    ...

    static config = (...params) => {
        return require('deep-extend')({}, ...params);
    };

    ...
}
```

Here's what I originally tried using the dynamic import syntax:

```js
export default class Module extends React.Component {
    ...

    static config = (...params) => {
        return import('deep-extend').then(MODULE => {
            return MODULE({}, ...params);
        });
    };

    ...
}
```

However, it doesn't work - it returns a promise instead of a function. I'm sure this is the expected behaviour, I just have no exposure to promises before so am finding it difficult to change my way of thinking and just don't get it.

What am I missing? How can I modify my above code to use dynamic imports?

Comment: Well, it seems that whatever function is calling `config()` now needs to wait for the promise to finish...

Comment: @MatthewHerbst it's a static method that can be used anywhere - wherever it's used will have no awareness of the promise

Comment: Static has no bearing on this. Do you not control the rest of the codebase? If you can't `config().then()` wherever it's called, then you can't use `import()` assuming `config` actually needs to return a value

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I can't really do `config().then()` as the old API is heavily used and a refactor is too big of an overhead unfortunately - was really hoping I could still keep just `config()` and have it return the value. But good to know it's not possible I guess. It seems a bit silly having to change my API to cater for the way I manage dependencies anyway...

Comment: Short term yes, long term more and more things will just be promises. Sorry it won't work out for you right now